# Удаление сразу из нескольких таблиц InnoDB в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Всем привет, может кто подскажет, где ошибка. Есть две таблицы ...

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product_categories`;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_categories` (
          `id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `parent_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
          `position` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
          `left` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
          `right` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
          `level` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
          `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          `type` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          PRIMARY KEY (id)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
      `productID` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `catID` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
      `productName` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `productInfo` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `productPrice` float(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (productID),
      FOREIGN KEY (catID) REFERENCES `product_categories` (parent_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE

CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Если выполнить этот код, то получим ошибку...

> `#1005 - Can't create table 'products' (errno: 150)`

Что не так?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй 2-ю таблицу создать так:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
    `productID` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `catID` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `productName` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `productInfo` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `productPrice` FLOAT(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (productID),
    INDEX catID (catID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_products_catID FOREIGN KEY (catID) -- Тут была ошибка
        REFERENCES `product_categories` (parent_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB 
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Для полей `productName` и `productInfo` COLLATE указывать необязательно. По умолчанию будет использоваться тот, что после скобки.

Comment: попробывал, тоже не работает.
Незнаю можно ли считать это за ответ скорее всего это новый вопрос, а можно ли так...
добавил индекс к таблице product_categories 
INDEX (parent_id)

и все заработало без ошибок.

Comment: Ну да, верно. Внешний ключ не может существовать без индекса. Это, кстати, должно было быть написано в тексте ошибки.